Redirecting mobile users according to their OS
I need to add a clickable ad banner on my WP site for mobile users so that i can redirect users to the releveant store according to their OS.
i.e. redirecting android users to play store, and iOS users to apple store.
Could you please help me do this?
Best regards

You'd have to try and base it on what's in the user-agent string their browser sends. But of course that is subject to change, and spoofable, so it's not a bulletproof solution. But why do you want to know? A web application should not really care what O/S the client is using...that's part of the beauty of the web! Are you wanting to direct the user to an app store - I think that's maybe what you meant? If so I wouldn't necessarily suggest automatically redirecting without the user confirming the choice, and letting them choose another option in case it's wrong. Once they select, you can link

Asuming that you want to send to App Store or playstore based on Google Device or android one way to do it would be to add Javascript in header.php of your Wordpress.
HTML of the Banner
 <a href="#" id="mobile-store-link">
    <img src="YOUR_BANNER_IMAGE_URL" alt="Download App" />
    </a>

Followrd by Script
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
        var storeLink = document.getElementById("mobile-store-link");

        // Define your store URLs
        var playStoreUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=YOUR_APP_ID";
        var appStoreUrl = "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/YOUR_APP_ID";

        if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
            // Redirect Android users to Play Store
            storeLink.setAttribute("href", playStoreUrl);
        } else if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
            // Redirect iOS users to Apple Store
                storeLink.setAttribute("href", appStoreUrl);
            } else {
                // Fallback if neither iOS nor Android
                storeLink.setAttribute("href", "#");
            }
        });
</script>

Do think about responsive banner image. CSS media query can be used to achieve this.

Thanks Ali, much appreciated.
